# Python. List comprehensions with not in and or

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a list of strings that I want to filter:

```
A = ['enc_1', 'enc_2', 'enc_lag', 'lag_1', 'lag_2', 'price', 'price_std']
```

If I need strings that contain EITHER 'enc' OR 'lag', I can do the following:

```
[_ for _ in A if ('enc' in _) or ('lag' in _)]

Output: ['enc_1', 'enc_2', 'enc_lag', 'lag_1', 'lag_2']
```

Everything is fine. However, if I need strings that contain NEITHER 'enc' NOR 'lag', a seemingly obvious solution doesn't work:

```
[_ for _ in A if ('enc' not in _) or ('lag' not in _)]

Output: ['enc_1', 'enc_2', 'lag_1', 'lag_2', 'price', 'price_std']
```

Judging by the result, I would expect an expression with AND to produce such an output ('enc_lag' would be removed), but for whatever reason OR does it instead. I am starting deeply questioning my understanding of OR and AND operators... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As a programmer you should be familiar with [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: "Does not contain A _or_ does not contain B" isn't "*neither* A nor B". You want "doesn't contain A _and_ doesn't contain B"!

Comment: If you really mean "strings that contain NEITHER 'enc' NOR 'lag'", then the result would be just `['price', 'price_std']`.  Is that the result you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want is `and` here. If the element must contain neither `'enc'` nor `'lag'`, then it must not contain `'enc'` AND must not contain `'lag'`.

```py
[_ for _ in A if ('enc' not in _) and ('lag' not in _)]
```

Alternatively, by applying De Morgan's law, we have:

```py
[_ for _ in A if not (('enc' in _) or ('lag' in _))]
```

Comment: @DanielHao `_` is just a variable here like `x`. Of course the naming could be improved.

Comment: Understood.  Just feel a little *weird* though.  +1

Comment: Many thanks, somehow I totally missed it. Should've thought of De Morgan's law right away.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an AND instead. You're checking if every value:

- contains enc OR
- contains lag

So, every value that has enc in it (true) doesn't have lag (false). which means your condition comes back true.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want it to return ['price', 'price_std'] in the not statement.

In your case take for example 'enc_1', ('enc' not in _) = False but then you say OR ('log' not in _) it would be True. If False or True = True. so enc_1 is True.

solution: [_ for _ in A if ('enc' not in _ and 'lag' not in _)]